# ErrorException Attempt to read property "category_name" on int

Tags: laravel

**To update the added categories, I encounter errors that are returned to me. I think there are functions missing or I wrote badly at the level of my controller**

I got this error

**ErrorException
Attempt to read property "category_name" on int**

How to solve that ?

Here is my controller CategorieController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Categorie;


class CategorieController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function ajoutercategorie(){
        return view('admin.ajoutercategorie');
    }

    public function sauvercategorie(Request $request){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required | max:255',
        ]);

        $categorie = Categorie::create($validatedData);

        return redirect('/ajoutercategorie')->with('status', 'La catégorie '
        .$categorie->category_name.' a été ajoutée avec succès');

    }

    public function categorie(){
        $categories = Categorie::get();
        return view('admin.categorie')->with('categories', $categories);
    }

    public function edit_categorie($id){
        $categorie = Categorie::find($id);
        return view('admin.editcategorie')->with('categorie', $categorie);
    }

    public function modifiercategorie(Request $request, Categorie $id){

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'category_name' => 'required | max:255',
        ]);

        $categorie = Categorie::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);

        return redirect('/categorie')->with('status', 'La catégorie'
        .$categorie->category_name. 'a été modifiée avec succès');

    }
}
```

Here my editcategorie.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.appadmin')

@section('title')
    Modifier la catégorie
@endsection

@section('contenu')


    <div class="row grid-margin">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Modifier la catégorie</h4>

                  @if (Session::has('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        {{Session::get('status')}}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('categories.modifiercategorie') }}">
                      @csrf
                    <fieldset>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cemail">Nom de la catégorie</label>
                        <input id="cemail" class="form-control" type="text" name="category_name" value="{{$categorie->category_name}}">
                      </div>

                      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Modifier">

                    </fieldset>

                    </form>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


@endsection

@section('scripts')
    {{--<script src="Administrateur/js/form-validation.js"></script>
    <script src="Administrateur/js/bt-maxLength.js"></script>--}}
@endsection
```

My categorie.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.appadmin')


@section('title')
    Catégorie
@endsection

@section('contenu')

          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Catégorie</h4>
              @if (Session::has('status'))
              <div class="alert alert-success">
                  {{Session::get('status')}}
              </div>
              @endif
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="order-listing" class="table">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Order #</th>
                            <th>Nom de la catégorie</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        @foreach ($categories as $categorie)

                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$categorie->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$categorie->category_name}}</td>
                            <td>
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="window.location ='{{url('/edit_categorie/' .$categorie->id)}}'">Modifier</button>
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Supprimer</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


@endsection

 @section('scripts')
    <script src="Administrateur/js/data-table.js"></script>
 @endsection


</body>

</html>
```

How can I solve this ?

I think the error comes from my function modifiercategorie in my CategorieController

Comment: You have `Categorie $id`, but then you do `Categorie::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);`... Why? `$id` is already a `Categorie` model instance, you don't need to query the database for it again. Also, correct syntax would be `Categorie::whereId($id->id)->update($validatedData)`, or, better yes, rename `$id` to `$categorie`, then just `$categorie->update($validatedData)`.

Comment: I tried this but I notice it works but the category name is not updated, it still keeps the old name instead of changing it to the new name. How to solve that ?

Comment: Ok, you need to do some debugging on your end. `dd($id)`, what does that return? Is it an `integer`, or a `Categorie` model instance? If it's a Model, then just do `$id->update($validatedData)` (or, like I said, rename `$id` to `$categorie`, then `$categorie->update($validatedData)`. If it is an `integer`, then `dd(Categorie::whereId($id)->first())`; if that is `null`, then you don't have a record that can be updated. If that is a `Categorie` model, then `Categorie::whereId($id)->update($validatedData)` would work. You seem confused on what `$id` and `$categorie` are so debug them in your code

Comment: is `category_name` fillable?

Comment: I tried all that but it always gives me a success even though the name is not updated. You have my code, could you see it again please? Or do you have any other code suggestions?

Comment: Yes it is  fillable

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here `$categorie = Categorie::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);` because `update` method returns count of updated columns. You should find a category.

Try to do this

```
...
$categorie = Categorie::whereId($id)->first()
$categorie->update($validatedData);
...
```

Comment: I tried your answers, sometimes for one it still gives me the error: **ErrorException
Attempt to read property "category_name" on int**. For Aro's answer, it returns me as an error: **Error
Call to a member function update() on null** . How to solve that ?

Comment: `Categorie::whereId($id)` is returning `null`, since `$id` is already an instance of your `Categorie` model. @MartialDenver check my comment on your question, and fix your code. You don't need `Categorie::whereId($id)->first()` at all.

Comment: I tried this but I notice it works but the category name is not updated, it still keeps the old name instead of changing it to the new name. How to solve that ? verey needo to solve

Comment: if you have this message * Error Call to a member function update() on null* it mean that you don't have a category by that id. You must throw 404

Comment: You can use `firstOrFail` instead of `first`

Answer (score -2):

in the method that you mentioned(modifiercategorie):

```
        $categorie = Categorie::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);
```

here you are doing wrong you cannot update it's data by Validate method.
you need to put data like this :

```
        $categorie = Categorie::whereId($id)->update(['category_name'=>$request->category_name]);
```

Comment: This is not it, sorry. `$request->validate()` returns an array of valid data, including `['category_name' => $request->input('category_name')]`; this code will produce the exact same error as before.

Comment: I tried this but I notice it works but the category name is not updated, it still keeps the old name instead of changing it to the new name. How to solve that ?